# Scala function to change attribute of class

Tags: scala

I created a class Door and want to write a function that changes the open status to whatever is the argument.

The below does not work. What would be the best way of doing that? (Sorry for the beginner question.)

```
class Door(var name: String,
          var open: Boolean){
        def open_door(newDoorState: Boolean): Unit = new Door(name, newDoorState)
        override def toString(): String =
"(" + name + ", " + newDoorState + ")"

}

var door = new Door("MyDoor",true)
door.name // "MyDoor"
door.open // true

door.open_door(false)
door.name // "MyDoor"
door.open // still true. I would like this to be false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Łukasz and Venkat Sudheer Reddy Aedama mentioned in their comments, the recommended way to mutate values in Scala is to use immutable objects.

This means that every change of object state you will be creating a new object with updated values. It's necessary for achieving referential transparency allowing programs to be free of side effects, which is considered a desirable property that makes code significantly easier to maintain.

In Scala there is a convenient mechanism called case classes. Let's look at how `Door` could be defined as a case class:

```scala
case class Door(name: String, open: Boolean) {
  def opened(open: Boolean) = copy(open = open)
}
```

As you may have noticed there are is no `var` or `val` before class arguments. This is because in case class every argument is assumed to be a `val`, making case classes immutable by default.

Another difference is that instead of creating a new instance with `new` operator, it uses a `copy` method, which allows to change the values of specified fields. It may be hard to see the benefit of doing it this way now, but it becomes very convenient when you are dealing with case classes with lot more fields.

Now you can instantiate `Door` and update it in the following way:

```scala
val door = Door("MyDoor", false)
door.name // "MyDoor"
door.open // false

val door2 = door.opened(true)
door2.name // "MyDoor"
door2.open // true
```

Another convenience provided by case classes is that you can instantiate them without using `new` keyword, which is a syntactic sugar for calling `Door.apply("MyDoor", false)`.

So far we have seen how to declare and use a case class for immutable data objects. But does it mean that we should always declare our classes this way?

The important property of case classes is that they are transparent. Which is imposed by the fact that all their fields are exposed as public `val`s. This is useful when you want to read object's properties the same way as they were stored.

On the other hand, if you don't want to expose the internals of your objects (so your class can be called opaque), for example to enforce some invariants, it might be a better idea to use standard Scala classes.

For general rules and tradeoffs associated with transparency vs opacity I recommend reading Li Haoyi's article [Strategic Scala Style: Designing Datatypes](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStyleDesigningDatatypes.html).

---

In some cases, for example if you want to improve performance or reduce memory footprint of your program, you may decide to use mutable class instead:

```scala
class Door(var name: String,
          var open: Boolean) {
  def openDoor(newDoorState: Boolean): Unit = 
    open = newDoorState
}

val door = new Door("MyDoor",true)
door.name // "MyDoor"
door.open // true

door.openDoor(false)
door.name // "MyDoor"
door.open // false
```

Just keep in mind that immutable object are generally preferred way of passing the data around, and you should design your programs to be referentially transparent by default, and when it becomes really necessary, then consider such micro-optimizations like changing your data structures to be mutable.

Also I'll add that in Scala there is a convention (that originates from Java) to use camel case for class fields and methods, so instead of naming your method `open_door` like in the original example, you should name it `openDoor`.

Comment: it would be worth mentioning that OP should use `camelCase` for method names, point out that it is generally better to use the first variant over the mutable one, drop vars if he wants to create a new object anyway and probably create a `case class Door(name: String, open: Boolean)` instead and implement `opened` method using `copy`.

Comment: As @Łukasz mentioned above:
`case class Door(name: String, isOpen: Boolean) {
    def openDoor(newDoorState: Boolean): Door = this.copy(isOpen = newDoorState)
  }`

Comment: Łukasz, Venkat Sudheer Reddy Aedama I am sorry for late reply, that was indeed a lazy answer. Thanks for your suggestions, I have expanded my answer now with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your open_door function returns a new door.  Instead, it should set the `open` attribute:

```
class Door(var name: String, var open: Boolean) {
  def openDoor(newDoorState: Boolean) {
    open = newDoorState
  }
  override def toString(): String = "(" + name + ", " + newDoorState + ")"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current open_door method creates new instance of Door, where open is set to newDoorState.

To achieve what you want, you have to do:

```
def open_door(newDoorState: Boolean): Unit {
  open = newDoorState
}
```

(Note the absense of equal sign before the function body. Also, you can drop ":Unit" part - it will be inferred.)

Comment: using the `=` is required. The procedure syntax was deprecated a few years ago. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7605

Comment: I see, thanks for noticing. A year ago I still used version of Scala where it was valid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, so far the answers were all object oriented. 
I'm adding a more functional answer, i.e. not changing the original Door class:

```
class Door{
       var name="MyDoor"
       var open_status=true
 def this(name:String, open_status:Boolean){
     this()
     this.open_status = open_status
 }

 override def toString = {
"%s is open is %s.".format(name, open_status)
 }
}

println(new Door)
println(new Door("MyDoor",false))
```